# Python Invoke module fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, invoke

I am trying to understand how the `invoke` module works in Python. I have installed the package using the `pip install` and I am trying to invoke a script in the following manner.

I create a `tasks.py` as `invoke` is on the search for it, and created a small task as shown below.

`tasks.py`

```
from invoke import task

@task(name = "webopener")
def openwebpage(c,url=None):
    if url:
        c.run(f"start {url}")
    else:
        print("I need a URL!")
```

I go to the directory and call :

```
E:\Test>invoke webopener
'invoke' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But the invoke seems to have been installed

```
E:\Test>pip install invoke
Requirement already satisfied: invoke in e:\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.7.3)
```

I read that we need to add it to Path. But what directory needs to be added? This does not happen while downloading or using other packages?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there are several options depending on if you're using [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or installing packages globally.

If you're using venv, you need to activate the profile with `& ./.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1` (assuming you're using PowerShell), in your case from `E:\Test`.

I haven't used pipenv yet, but the solution is probably similar.

If you're not using any environment management stuff (i.e. packages are installed globally), you need to add `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts` (depending on the Python version you're using) to your `PATH`. This is a good idea even if you do use venv and/or pipenv, I've found.